# How to join dataframes with JSON-encoded rows on specific path?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking to join 2 data frames (both containing large volumes of JSON), but under a specific path. I was hoping I can do this within the same operation and not having to transform it as an RDD after the JOIN, I assume this is possible to do elegantly via Spark SQL.

The content of both objects are dynamic so I dont know the entire structure in advance, but the top level path in each is constant

object 1 document

```
{
   "object1": {
        "element1" "element1value"
        ...
   }

}
```

object 2 document

```
{

   "object2": {

    "element1" "element1value"
    ...
   }

}
```

Expected Result

```
{
   "object1Parent": {
        "element1" "element1value"
        ...
   },
   "object2Parent": {

       "object2": {

        "element1" "element1value"
        ...
       }
   }

}
```

Join operation

```
SQL: "SELECT * FROM object1 r JOIN object2 s ON r.element1 = s.element2"
```

Comment: See here and be enlightened: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-and-write-json-file/

Comment: Thanks, but from what I can see that example reads and writes JSON without transforming the structure. Using a Struct it's easy to change the names of the elements, but I can't see how to change the JSON path structure itself, without reprocessing the dataframe.

Comment: well you can select and write as json, may be I am too quick.

Answer (score 1):

> The content of both objects are dynamic so I dont know the entire structure in advance

That seems like an argument against Spark SQL (and more for RDD API) since it's the Optimizer that makes Spark SQL so great and it has to have information about the schema to apply optimizations to your structured query.

That however could not necessarily be true per the requirements.

> but the top level path in each is constant

If `object1` is always followed by `element1` and so is `object2`, and they are used in `join`, that could be enough.

You simply have to "destructure" the opaque JSON format and make it row-like. Use [from_json](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) standard functions, e.g.

> **from_json(e: Column, schema: Column): Column**
>
> **from_json(e: Column, schema: DataType): Column**
>
> Parses a column containing a JSON string into a MapType with StringType as keys type, StructType or ArrayType of StructTypes with the specified schema. Returns null, in the case of an unparseable string.

That part of schema being dynamic could be handled by this `schema` argument that could change at runtime. It could be created as part of your Spark application (when the input argument is `schema: DataType`) or could come as part of the DataFrame with your input data (when `schema: Column`).

You could also use `get_json_object` or `json_tuple` standard functions.

As of Spark 2.4.0, you could also use `schema_of_json` to infer schema of a column in DDL format for the earlier functions.

Lots of options, *aren't there?*

### (pseudo) Code

Let's assume the following two datasets with JSON-encoded rows.

```
val object1 = Seq("""
{
  "object1": {
    "element1": "element1value",
    "object1_only": 1
  }
}
""").toDF("json")

val object2 = Seq("""
{
  "object2": {
    "element1": "element1value",
    "object2_only": 2
  }
}
""").toDF("json")
```

You could extract the field to join on using `get_json_object` standard function.

```
val obj1_el1 = object1
  .select(get_json_object($"json", "$.object1.element1"))
scala> obj1_el1.show
+-----------------------------------------+
|get_json_object(json, $.object1.element1)|
+-----------------------------------------+
|                            element1value|
+-----------------------------------------+
```

A joined dataset would then be as follows:

```
val o1 = object1
  .withColumn("join_column", get_json_object($"json", "$.object1.element1"))
val o2 = object2
  .withColumn("join_column", get_json_object($"json", "$.object2.element1"))
val s = o1.join(o2, Seq("join_column"))
```